# SQL INNER JOIN return parent row values only on first match

Tags: sql, oracle

Folks,
      All am looking for is to extend the INNER JOIN. Let me just get to the point. I have two tables Dept & Emp. One Dept can have multiple Emp's & not the other way around.

```
Table Dept
Dept_id   Dept_Name
1         IT
2         HR
3         Other

Table Emp
Emp_id   Dept_id   Emp_Name
11       1         John
12       1         Jill
13       2         Jack
14       3         Jared
15       1         Jim
16       1         Jarret
17       2         Jacob

I need to JOIN it on Dept_id

Expected Results
Dept_id   Dept_name Emp_id   Emp_Name
1         IT        11       John
NULL      NULL      12       Jill
NULL      NULL      15       Jim
NULL      NULL      16       Jarret
2         HR        13       Jack
NULL      NULL      17       Jacob
3         Other     14       Jared
```

Hope I conveyed what i want precisely. Its just a regular Inner Join on a Foreign Key Constraint. But, I want the values from the First Table (Dept) to be NULL-ed except for the First Match. That being said, I don't care what's the first match. See it below - Just the result for the Dept_id 1.

```
Expected Results (Only for Dept_id = 1)
It could be

Dept_id   Dept_name Emp_id   Emp_Name
1         IT        11       John
NULL      NULL      12       Jill
NULL      NULL      15       Jim
NULL      NULL      16       Jarret

OR

Dept_id   Dept_name Emp_id   Emp_Name
1         IT        15       Jim
NULL      NULL      12       Jill
NULL      NULL      11       John
NULL      NULL      16       Jarret

OR

Two other possibilities.
```

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the long explanation even though its a simple case.

Comment: Will you try left join?

Comment: Left join wouldn't get the results they are looking for. Looks more like they are trying to group the results, and only allow values in Dept_id and Dept_name on the first match for each dept. I'm curious as to why you would want to do this as this would make the data appear that Jill Jim and Jarret have no department. The proper thing to do would be to have the values in all columns, and handle the formatting in your code that you're using to display the results. With what is being asked, if you change the sort on the client you would have unreadable data

Comment: You're right. Its a crazy query. I am trying to do a part which my application should be doing. But, I am sure that there's a way to do it through query & wanna know that. Thanks for the Comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Ic. that this is a crazy query that seems to be doing something that your application should be doing instead of your sql query, that being said, it's fun to write those queries :)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Dept_id ELSE NULL END AS Dept_id,
       CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN Dept_name ELSE NULL END AS Dept_name,
        Emp_id, Emp_Name
FROM Dept d
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_id ORDER BY Emp_Name) AS RowNumber, 
       Dept_id, Dept_name, Emp_id, Emp_Name
FROM Emp ) t on t.Dept_id = d. Dept_id
```

Comment: I guess this is for some kind of "ASCII report"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess there might be situations when this is indeed the best approach!

Comment: Thats exactly what i want. Thanks Bassam.

Comment: @Bassam - I was aware of the CASE statement, but not good enough to use PARTITION coupled with it.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'm not really sure why you want this result. Formatting is usually best left for the UI layer and NOT your database server. Doing it this way makes the data look like the non-first-employees for each department actually do not have a department, and it fundamentally breaks any sorting or editing functions you may have in your client.

However, you could try:

```
SELECT FormattedDept.Dept_id, FormattedDept.Dept_Name, Emp.Emp_id, Emp.Emp_Name
FROM Emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Dept.Dept_id, Dept.Dept_Name, MIN(Emp_id) AS Emp_id
    FROM Dept
    INNER JOIN Emp ON Dept.Dept_id = Emp.Dept_id
    GROUP BY Dept.Dept_id, Dept.Dept_Name
) FormattedDept ON Emp.Dept_id = FormattedDept.Dept_id
    AND Emp.Emp_id = FormattedDept.Emp_id
ORDER BY Emp.Dept_id, Emp.Emp_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd800/57)

Answer (score 1):

```
select case
          when lag(d.dept_id) over (partition by d.dept_id order by e.emp_id) = d.dept_id then null
          else d.dept_id 
       end as dept_id,
       case
          when lag(d.dept_name) over (partition by d.dept_id order by e.emp_id) = d.dept_name then null
          else d.dept_name 
       end as dept_name,
       e.emp_id,
       e.emp_name
from dept d
  join emp e on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
order by d.dept_id, d.dept_name, e.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in my comment above, I'm not sure that you would really want the results to return in the way you are asking. Consider this. If the result set was exported to Excel, and a user changed the sort, then you would lose what dept employee 1-x was in and employee 0 would still show their department. I would suggest you group by Dept_id, and not null out the dept_id and dept_name. Handle the display of that data in your display code.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH newRecord
AS
(
   SELECT "Emp_id", "Dept_id", "Emp_Name",
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Dept_id" ORDER BY "Emp_id" ASC) RN
   FROM Emp  
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN b."Dept_id" ELSE NULL END AS "Dept_ID",
        CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN b."Dept_Name" ELSE NULL END AS "Dept_Name",
        "Emp_id", "Emp_Name"
FROM    newRecord a 
        INNER JOIN Dept b ON a."Dept_id" = b."Dept_id"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd800/29)

Answer (score 0):

because i cant think of a reason you would want that other then reporting purposes then you can also do this by using SQL*Plus formmating.

just run the following command before the query in SQL*Plus

```
break on dept_id skip 1
```

Enjoy.